# IIS 7 how to call script if file exists

Tags: php, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

Not sure if this is possible. I want to run a php script everytime a page on my website is run. So if i got to example.com/test/runme.php i want to run checkme.php then continue on to runme.php. Kind of like when there is a 404 error you can tell it to run a script, i want it to run a script on a successful file.Basically checking to see if the machine is authorized to view it. Im running 2008 r2 server iis7. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom HTTP Module for IIS, I suspect what would be easier though is just putting a require() in each of your php scripts to call the other one first.